# Getting 415 unsupported Media Type using Postman (Native app)

Tags: spring

There are many posts related to this issue. But after trying out all the options, still haven't been able to figure out what's wrong. Trying to post a file. UI code is not ready so testing the backend spring code using Postman app.

**Method Declaration**

```
@POST
@Path("/docUpload")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response docUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file);
```

**Method definition**

```
   @Override
        public Response docUpload(MultipartFile file) {
        // Logic
        }
```

I am using Postman Native APP to send the file in the below manner. Not explicitly setting the Content-Type to multipart/form-data in Postman. Postman is doing it on it's own.

Getting the response from server as 415 Unsupported Media Type

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReRPR.jpg)

**Console Logs**

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-09-16 23:59:10.318 GMT","level":"ERROR","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-2","logger":"c.a.i.l.J.S.docUpload","msg":"res","s-msg":{"duration(ms)":58,"reqHeaders":{"accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","authorization":"Basic xxxxxxxxxx","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"29136","content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------875619922967095234704119","host":"localhost:8080","postman-token":"bf7ad78c-7ac8-48ce-a377-862ded1497bf","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5"},"method":"POST","uri":"/api/identification/docUpload","resHeaders":{},"statusCode":415},"seq":126,"format":"nf-v1.0"}
```